# Slow Mysql Queries

Tags: mysql, performance

I'm having issues with Wordpress being too slow. I discovered it's because of MySQL queries. They take sometimes 2 - 10s - way too long.

I installed Query Monitor to see what's causing the problem: https://cdn.pbrd.co/images/GRit4ZF.png

Comment: Is this the only "slow" query? Also, check your Plugins. 2 seconds for the options is pretty slow.

Comment: @kuchenundkakao it is not the only slow query. There are others, but it happens only sometimes.

Comment: Well, if there are more slow queries, maybe a) the MySQL Server is really really slow, or if the MySQL Server is a different machine than the Webserver, maybe the Connection between MySQL Server and Webserver is really slow. Maybe there is a PHPMyAdmin on the MySQL-Server where you can check if the same query in it is as slow?

Comment: @kuchenundkakao the server is the same. It's running on VPS.

Comment: Did you try running the query within PHPMyAdmin?

Comment: @kuchenundkakao it is slow only sometimes. I wasn't able to reproduce it in the PMA

Comment: You may find this URL very helpful.  www.jetprofiler.com to find Top Queries, Top Tables with a two hour history of what it has found.  Set polling interval to 10 seconds and there will be no impact on your MySQL server.  View my profile, Network profile and we have free Utility Scripts available for your download and use to improve performance.

Answer (score 1):

WP options (which is one of the most basic and used storage APIs) can be stored with or without "autoload" setting. Usually this is reasonable, since many options will be checked on *each and every* page load, so loading them in bulk during core load is much more efficient than individually.

Problems usually start when two problems compound:

1. the *total* amount of options gets significantly large (let's say hundreds of thousands, but it depends);
2. large amount and/or size of options are marked for autoload which *shouldn't* be.

There is no generic solution to this issue, since there is no generic common cause.

You would need to examine *your* actual data to see which options get loaded and what exactly happens to be a bottleneck.

Comment: There are 433 rows in SQL. Is it too much?

Comment: Less than a thousand is definitely too few too matter. So it's probably about size of options or possibly something choking in MySQL server itself.